# Can't see edit suggestions on Google Chrome for Android

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, mobile-chrome

One can't see edit suggestions on Google Chrome for Android.

Example from [What is the best technology for generating Indic Languages (Hindi, Punjabi , Gujrati) PDFs in Java?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/70443/what-is-the-best-technology-for-generating-indic-languages-hindi-punjabi-guj):

The following question has no edit button when viewed on Google Chrome for Android:

[image]

whereas it has an edit button when viewed on Google Chrome for Microsoft Windows:

[image]

Both Google Chrome for Microsoft Windows and Google Chrome for Android are connected to my Stack Exchange account.

Once the edit suggestion has been processed, then Google Chrome for Android does show the edit button.

Comment: I don't think this is something they'll fix - the focus seems to be on making the full site responsive, and the responsive version does show the edit button.

Comment: Reproduced on **both** Chrome and Firefox for Android **if** you are not using the "Full Site" - go to the bottom of the screen, click on [Full Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IwEV.jpg) and reload the webpage to make the "Edit" link appear.

Comment: @muru thanks, is the responsive version the version we get after clicking on "full site"?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt yes, that's the one, (also indicated by Rob).

Comment: @muru thanks do you know whether stack exchange announced any timeline when the responsive version of the website will be ready to use on the phone?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I think the intention is that it's *already* ready for use on the phone; it's just not the default yet. I couldn't find any mention of when they'll make it the default, though.

Comment: @muru I see. Definitely not ready to use now, e.g. some fon't sizes are way too small (can't be properly solved by zooming in).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt those should be reported - I'd imaging that would get to the top of the to-do queue quite fast.

Comment: `... not ready to use now, e.g. some font sizes are way too small (can't be properly resolved by zooming in). – Franck Dernoncourt 5 hours ago` --- Which fonts Frank?, how much did you want to zoom in ... Here's an example [answer with tiny fonts](https://mathoverflow.net/a/355386/122794) - Here is un-zoomed and fully zoomed in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIvuC.jpg --- How could it be better?

Comment: @Rob [Some fonts are way too small to be used on the responsive design on Chrome for a regular Android phone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345492/178179)