# Some fonts are way too small to be used on the responsive design on Chrome for a regular Android phone

Tags: discussion, responsive-design, android, mobile-chrome, font-size

Some fonts are way too small to be used on the responsive design on Chrome for a regular Android phone.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Profile pages aren’t responsive, though.

Comment: @Catija thanks, how does one one whether a page is responsive?

Comment: Responsive generally means it adapts to changes in page width in different views. So if it’s side scrolling or there’s other wonky things like you have to zoom to see the content when you’re on a small screen, it’s probably not responsive.

Comment: You should charge your phone.

Comment: The mobile site is almost always better. You can switch to it with the "Mobile" link at the bottom.

Comment: Can you try opening the chrome menu (the icon with 3 dots) and make sure that "Desktop site" is NOT checked? If it was checked before, unchecking it might solve the problem for the question and question list pages.

Comment: @Luuklag I live a dangerous life.

Comment: @KodosJohnson thanks, I use desktop site on purpose, following  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345439/cant-see-edit-suggestions-on-google-chrome-for-android#comment1157376_345439 Is the website responsive too when "desktop" is not checked?

Comment: That other question just says to use "full site" by clicking on the link in the footer. I am talking about the "Desktop site" setting which is a site specific chrome setting. You should keep "full site" turned on here, but with "desktop site" setting turned off in chrome. The site is **not** responsive otherwise. Keep in mind not all pages are responsive yet, like the profile page. In that case you have to zoom in wherever you want an up-close view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some of those pages (the question list and question page), the reason that the text may look small is because you have the **Desktop site** setting turned on in chrome. See the following screenshot.

[image: Chrome with Desktop site disabled]

If you don't have **Desktop site** disabled, the pages won't be responsive. Keep in mind that other pages (like the profile page) are not responsive yet but I believe they will be soon.

Comment: I see, thanks! I hadn't realized that was different. If wasting screen space was a crime, someone at Stack Exchange Inc. would be getting life with that responsive mode :-/

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Agreed, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343387/responsive-design-of-the-question-list-isnt-compact-enough-on-small-screens

Comment: Note that (currently) there are some situations on mobile devices where you *need* to select both Desktop site and Full site. Eg, trying to improve a suggested edit. In the mobile site, the `edit` button disappears on posts that have a pending suggested edit.

Comment: @PM2Ring hmm I can't reproduce that. You are talking about improving a suggested edit int he "Suggested Edits" review queue, right?

Comment: @KodosJohnson No, I'm talking about improving a suggested edit directly on a Q&A page, not in the review queue. For example, if I suggest an edit to your answer the [edit] button under your answer will disappear in the Mobile view.